# Unable to connect to the Maximo server via RMI protocol

Tags: java, maximo

I am trying to connect to MAXIMO using Java via RMI protocol, but continuously getting error: "Unable to connect". The server is up and running, but RMI services are not available.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the following properties
mxe.rmi.enabled = 1
mxe.rmi.port = 1099
If the port value is set to zero, the server will use any available port.
You should check the startup log to verify on which port the server is running.